# NVDIA GT 740 can't dual monitor after installing Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg, multiple-monitors

I know it's newbee question. But i couldn't fix this problem. So i just started installing Ubuntu 16.10

My PC is Optiplex 3020 with nvidia GT 740 vga, after i installed Ubuntu, the vga driver automatically choose nvdia graphic drivers 367.57 graphic drivers

driver automatically installed:
[image: driver automatically installed]

but the 2nd monitor (the one that the cable plug in to VGA card) dont displaying anything and when i check the x server setting, i got this :

no screen detected:
[image: no screen detected]

can someone help me...

Thanks

My display details:

```
*-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GK107 [GeForce GT 740]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:33 memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:f7000000-f707ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:31 memory:f7400000-f77fffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```